# Error #1009 : onenterFrameHandler when MouseEvent.CLICK include in button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got a problem when making a slide button function using MovieClip (root).

```
addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onenterFrameHandler);
```

when given a command button .. `addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_20);` when I click button, I get the output

> TypeError: Error # 1009: Can not access a property or method of a null object reference.
>   at index_fla :: MainTimeline / onenterFrameHandler ()

this is my code:

```
var myVar:Boolean;
MovieClip(root).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);
MovieClip(root).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);

function onenterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
if (MovieClip(root).mouseY < 500)
    {
      myVar=false;
    }
if (MovieClip(root).mouseY > 500)
    {
       myVar=true;
    }

if (MovieClip(root).mouseX > 1266 && myVar==true)
{
imgbar.nextFrame();
} else {
    imgbar.play();
}
if (MovieClip(root).mouseX < 100 && myVar==true)
{
imgbar.prevFrame();
} else {
    imgbar.play();
}
    if (MovieClip(root).mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 1266 && myVar==true)
    {
        imgbar.stop();
    }
}
```

and in button layer i fill code to command my button/movieclip;

```
    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(80, "Scene 2");
}
```

please help me

Comment: Something is obviously not defined, or not available to the scope of you enterFrame handler.  Where do you define `imgbar`?

Comment: its structure like this; scene1: imgBar: imgBarinside: button. ENTER_FRAME listener function I put in scene1 (Actions layer) and I put in a MovieClip imgBarinside mouseClickHandler MouseEventCLICK to execute commands. I structure it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the scene "Scene 2", some or all of your MovieClips are no longer present on the stage. Thus, the ENTER_FRAME handler can no longer find `imgbar`, and this causes the error.  To get rid of it, include the `imgbar` clip (with the same stage name!) as in the previous scene, or remove the ENTER_FRAME listener if `imgbar` is no longer present:

```
function onenterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (!imgbar) root.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);
     // the rest stays the same
}
```

Comment: thanks let me explain, I have 2 scane, imgbar (some scrool image / button) is on scene1 (button included), its structure is like this; scene1: imgBar: imgBarinside: button. ENTER_FRAME listener function I put in scene1 (Actions layer) and I put in a MovieClip imgBarinside mouseClickHandler MouseEventCLICK to execute commands. I structure it wrong? Because if MouseEventCLICK omitted then no problem will be running normally, I do not think there is a problem with the use of two scenes, but I do not know.

Comment: and, if   'MovieClip(root).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);'   i try to included your solution but onenterFrameHandler is unidentified because not one layer Actions, thanks.

Comment: I've changed my answer.  Have a look.

Comment: Well the message remains the same, TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at index_fla::MainTimeline/onenterFrameHandler()

Comment: I'll try to make just one scene, perhaps to be working, I will tell later

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
function onenterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (!imgbar) root.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);
     // the rest stays the same
}
```

yeah I found it with little modification, thanks for your advice, **weltraumpirat**, this is the final code:

```
    var myVar:Boolean=false;
    MovieClip(root).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);
    MovieClip(root).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_28);


function onenterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
if (MovieClip(root).mouseY < 500)
    {
      myVar=false;
    }
if (MovieClip(root).mouseY > 500)
    {
       myVar=true;
    }

if (MovieClip(root).mouseX > 1266 && myVar==true)
{
imgbar.nextFrame();
} else {
    imgbar.play();
}
if (MovieClip(root).mouseX < 100 && myVar==true)
{
imgbar.prevFrame();
} else {
    imgbar.play();
}
    if (MovieClip(root).mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 1266 && myVar==true)
    {
        imgbar.stop();
    }
    if (!imgbar)root.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenterFrameHandler);
}

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_28(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(root).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onenterFrameHandler);

}
```